# How to encapsulate transferring bytes between two containers

Tags: c++, encapsulation

I have two independent classes that each maintain a buffer of limited size:

```cpp
class A {
private:
    std::deque<uint8_t> buffer;
    size_t max_size;
};

class B {
private:
    static const size_t MAX_SIZE = 1024;
    uint8_t buffer[MAX_SIZE];
}
```

Now, I also have a function C that isn't a member of A or B. This function needs to take (i.e. remove) as many bytes as possible from the *beginning* of A and write it to B. Ofc no buffer overflows allowed.

Question: How do I do this efficiently while ensuring that A and B are encapsulated? I.e. A, B and C do not know how the others are implemented.

Things I *don't* want, for obvious reasons:

- A exposes a public method that returns a non-const iterator to deque
- B exposes a public method that returns a non-const pointer to the array

Comment: Is there any specific reason to disallow these options: `A exposes a public method that returns a non-const iterator to deque` and `B exposes a public method that returns a non-const pointer to the array`?

Comment: @Kunal Puri I don't want A or B to be able to accidentally modified by other code and potentially violate the max size constraint. Besides, it's implementation detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`class A` returns a **const** iterator via a new public method.
`class B` exposes a method to copy those bytes in.

```
class A {
public:
    const std::deque<uint8_t>& getBuffer() const
    {
        return buffer;
    }
private:
    std::deque<uint8_t> buffer;
    size_t max_size;
    size_t current_size;
};

class B {
public:
    B() : max_size(MAX_SIZE), current_size(0)
    {
    }
    void Transfer(const std::deque<uint8_t>& data)
    {
        size_t remaining = max_size - current_size;
        size_t toCopy = data.size() > remaining  ? remaining : data.size();
        for (size_t i = 0; i < toCopy; i++)
        {
            buffer[i+current_size] = data[i];
        }
        current_size += toCopy;
    }
private:
    static const size_t MAX_SIZE = 1024;
    uint8_t buffer[MAX_SIZE];
};


CopyAToB(const A& a, B& b)
{
    b.Transfer(a.getBuffer());
}
```

Comment: Nice. So the rule of thumb is "allow free read, but regulate write"?

Comment: More appropriately: Reading from A is *const* and writing into `B` is via a well defined *contract*.

Answer (score 2):

Mimic standard containers. Use `begin` and `end`. This is the minimal interface I see for your use case:

```cpp
class A {
private:
    std::deque<uint8_t> buffer_;
    size_t max_size_;

public:
    using const_iterator = decltype(buffer_)::const_iterator;

    auto begin() const -> const_iterator { return buffer_.begin(); }
    auto end() const -> const_iterator { return buffer_.end(); }
};

class B {
private:
    static const size_t MAX_SIZE = 1024;
    std::array<uint8_t, MAX_SIZE> buffer_;

public:

    /// fills the buffer with elements in [first, last)
    /// excessive elements are ignored
    /// returns the number of successfully filled elements

    template <class It>
    auto fill_as_much_as_possible(It first, It last) -> std::size_t
    {
        auto in_size = std::distance(first, last);
        if (in_size > static_cast<decltype(in_size)>(MAX_SIZE))
        {
            last = first;
            std::advance(last, MAX_SIZE);
        }

        auto out_last = std::copy(first, last, buffer_.begin());

        return std::distance(buffer_.begin(), out_last);
    }
};

auto foo(const A& a, B& b)
{
    b.fill_as_much_as_possible(a.begin(), a.end());
}
```